# Finding the radical of ideal $(y^4-x^2, x^2 - xy^2)$ without using Nullstellensatz

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I am trying to understand how to calculate radicals of ideals. Suppose we have $I = (y^4 - x^2, x^2-xy^2)$. I want to find $\sqrt{I}$.

My attempt is the following: since $y^4-x^2 = (y^2 - x)(y^2 + x) = (y^2 - x)y^2 + (y^2 - x)x$, we have $I = ((y^2 - x)y^2 + (y^2 - x)x, x(y^2 - x)) = ((y^2 - x)y^2, (y^2 - x)x)$. I have tried randomly to prove that some directly written ideals are the needed ones, but failed. The last attempt was that $\sqrt{I} = ((y^2 - x)y, (y^2 - x)x)$. One inclusion is obvious, but other I failed to prove. Any hints on how to calculate it directly without using the Nullstellensatz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you want to treat this as an exercise in doing algebra **without** the Nullstellensatz. However, I still think it would be sensible to use the Nullstellensatz at the very least to come up with a **hypothesis** for what $\sqrt{I}$ ought to be. You are very welcome to proceed to prove this hypothesis some other way if you wish.

Indeed, it's easy to see that the vanishing set for the ideal $I$ is the parabola $V(y^2 - x) \subset \mathbb A^2$. So $\sqrt{I}$ ought to be $(y^2 - x)$.

Now, let's see if we can prove that $\sqrt{I} = (y^2 - x)$ without using the Nullstellensatz.

**Proving that $(y^2 - x) \subset \sqrt{I}$.**  Observe that $(y^2 - x)^2 = (y^2 - x)y^2 - (y^2 - x)x$, which is certainly an element in $I$, since you know that $I = ((y^2 - x)y^2, (y^2 - x)x)$. Thus $y^2 - x \in \sqrt{I}$.

**Proving that $\sqrt{I} \subset (y^2 - x)$.** Perhaps the simplest approach is to observe that $(y^2 - x)$ is a prime ideal in $k[x, y]$. (One way to see that $(y^2 - x)$ is a prime ideal in $k[x, y]$ is to observe that $k[x,y]/(y^2 - x) \cong k[y]$ is an integral domain. Another way is to observe that the element $y^2 - x$ is irreducible in $k[x, y]$, and is therefore prime, since $k[x, y]$ is a UFD.) Anyway, from the expression $I = ((y^2 - x)y^2, (y^2 - x)x)$, it is clear that $I \subset (y^2 - x)$. If $f \in \sqrt{I}$, then $f^k \in I$ for some $k > 0$. Hence $f^k \in (y^2 - x)$. But $(y^2 - x)$ is a *prime* ideal, so in fact, $f \in (y^2 - x)$. Thus $\sqrt{I} \subset (y^2 - x)$.

Comment: After certain time of trying not using Nullstellensatz at all, i found this deal rather difficult for me, so you approach seams very good and the most rational, it's usefull for me, thank you.